# Add search parameter if condition is true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have code in my controller where i want filter some records for non-authorized users:

```
unless admin_signed_in?
  @posts = Post.where(hidden: false)
else
  @posts = Post.all
end
```

I tried to refactoring this, but can't make right query

```
@posts = Post.where(hidden: if admin_signed_in? ? true : false )
```

Output:

```
.../app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n' in_signed_in? ? true : false )
```

Comment: Try without `if`: `@posts = Post.where(hidden: admin_signed_in? ? true : false )`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an syntax error. you are using both `if` and `ternary (? :)`. Just change it to

```
@posts = Post.where(hidden: admin_signed_in?)
```

You don't need to pass `true` and `false` manually

**NOTE:**
But, it will not return you the posts with `hidden = false` if `admin_signed_in?` returns true

So, you might want to change it to

```
@posts = Post.where(({hidden: true} if admin_signed_in?))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your refactoring will not work, because `Post.all` will not return the same as `Post.where(hidden: true)`. The later will only list posts that *are* hidden, but not visible ones.

I would refactor the code to something like:

```
@posts = Post.all
@posts = @posts.where(hidden: false) unless admin_signed_in?
```

Comment: I removed all additional methods before post my question

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the ternary is the "if"

```
@posts = Post.where(hidden: if admin_signed_in? ? true : false )
```

Should be

```
@posts = Post.where(hidden: admin_signed_in? ? true : false )
```

And of course you can consider the other solutions posted.

Stefan has pointed out that admins will only see hidden posts, not all posts, so if you're going to stick with the ternary then you really want...

```
@posts = Post.where(hidden: admin_signed_in? ? [true,  false, nil] : false )
```

Comment: Caveat: admins will only see hidden posts.

Answer (score 0):

`unless` with `else` is quite confusing. I'd change it to:

```
if admin_signed_in?
  @posts = Post.all
else
  @posts = Post.where(hidden: false)
end
```

Other than that, I think the code reads just fine.

However, you could replace it with a ternary operator:

```
@posts = admin_signed_in? ? Post.all : Post.where(hidden: false)
```